Issue when drawing a rotated picture wpf
I Have this code to draw an imaged from video.. the image has to be rotated:
 int rotation = image.RotationAngle;


 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 mediaPlayer.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
 mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(image.Key));
 mediaPlayer.MediaFailed += (sender, e) => OnMediaFailed(sender, e, dc, image, ref rect);
 sw.Start();
 while (!(mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth > 0 && !image.IsVideoProcessingError))
 {
     if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000)
     {
         image.IsVideoProcessingError = true;
         break;
     }
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
 }

 var duration = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks;
 mediaPlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(duration / 5));

 var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

 using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
 {
     var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(rotation, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth / 2, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight / 2);
     drawingContext.PushTransform(rotateTransform);
     drawingContext.DrawVideo(mediaPlayer, new Rect(0, 0, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight));
 }

 renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

 var pixels = new uint[mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth * mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoHeight];


 renderTargetBitmap.CopyPixels(pixels, mediaPlayer.NaturalVideoWidth * 4, 0);


 im.Image = renderTargetBitmap;
              

 mediaPlayer.Close();
 mediaPlayer = null;

 _dc.DrawImage(im.Image, rect);

I want the image to fill my rect but when rotated is just vertically stretched but not horizonatally

When not rotated is correctly displayed (stretched vertically and horizontally):

What can I do?  Thanks!

when you manipulate Transform, it does not recalculate the stretching /parent Layout, so you would need to call recalculation manually from your code to update stretching of the elements

@ Demon I have to reset renderTargetBitmap? or create a new one maybe with  inverted heigth and width?

Based on the code I assume you have some sort of parent where you place your image (maybe a Viewbox or something) which has assigned the stretching you desire. in order this to take effect, you have to invalidate layout (https://i.sstatic.net/Fkf4o.png)

You are creating a RenderTargetBitmap with the width and height of the video, then you draw a rotated rectangle with the same dimensions into that bitmap. How is "fill my rect" then supposed to work? Please clarify what exactly you are trying to do.

Try setting Vertical and HorizontalAlignment of the Rectangle to other than "Stretch". (I don't think you really intend for the image to be "stretched"; you just want the Rectangle to fit around it; based on your definition of "correct").
